# How to get selected file from OneDrive File Picker?

Tags: laravel, onedrive

I am integrating the OneDrive File Picker in my Laravel application.

After selection of file(s) from picker, I am receiving the selected file id and its parent driveId [just these two params]. After this, I am not able to get this selected file.

This is the picker snippet:

[image: picker snippet]

And this is the data I am receiving on selection:

[image: data on selection]